# How do you test whether a field is of type "select" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do you test an input field for type "select", e.g. for a radio button, it's

```
if($('#' + field).attr('type') == 'radio'{
....
}
```

What do you write for a select box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), like this:

```
if($('#' + field).is('select')) {
```

Or check [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) only for *that* element type like this (a bit slower):

```
if($('select#' + field).length) {
```

Or [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.nodeName) (or [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName)) like this:

```
if($('#' + field)[0].tagName == 'SELECT') {
```

Or without jQuery at all (fastest):

```
if(document.getElementById(field).tagName == 'SELECT') {
```